# Use sort method and JOptionPane to have user input 10 numbers and output be the 10 numbers sorted

Tags: java, sorting

This is what I have so far:

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Aukeemhw3 {

```
/**
 * 
 * @param numberSort the purpose is to sort 10 input numbers
 */

public static void numInputSort(int[] numberSort){

    for(int i = 0; i < (numberSort.length - 1); i++){

        int min = i;

                for(int j = i; j < (numberSort.length); j++){
                        if(numberSort[j] < numberSort[min])
                            min = j;
                }
                int temp = numberSort[min];
                numberSort[min] = numberSort[i];
                numberSort[i] = temp;
    }
}
/*
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Request for user to enter 10 numbers

    String[] numbers;
    numbers = new String[10];

    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter " + numbers + "Values: ");

    numImportSort(int[] numbers);


}
```

}

I keep getting errors with everything I try when calling my method at the last line. I can't figure out how to properly code my main argument to ask the user to input 10 numbers then call my sort method numInputSort to sort the 10 numbers being input.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of errors in the main method. What you should do to fix:

- JOptionPane returns String so you should enter your numbers so that
  it can be converted to numbers, with some sort of delimiter
- Split and convert to numbers
- Assemble and int array and call the method

Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Request for user to enter 10 numbers

    int[] numbers = new int[10];

    String sNumbers =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number values, split with comma: ");

    String[] singleNumbers = sNumbers.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < singleNumbers.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(singleNumbers[i].trim());
    }
    numInputSort(numbers);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(numbers), "sorted",  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: Can I use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog to display the results to the user? If so which variable or String would I use to tell the program to locate and display those 10 sorted numbers to the user?

Comment: you can use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog I've edited my answer